# Rust confusion about specific package #2

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

Still trying to run [this script](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-parse-microsoft-word-documents-docx-in-rust-d62a4f56ba94) here. And still a Rustacean learner.

Yesterday I [had a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76632095/rust-confusion-about-specific-package/76632176#76632176) with the docx_rs/docx-rs crate. Enlightenment from at54321.

But the script still doesn't run. It appears to have a problem with a crate called `clap`.

```
D:\My documents\...\word_file>cargo run
   Compiling word_file v0.1.0 (D:\My documents\software projects\EclipseWorkspace\py_exp\src\rust_2023-07A\word_file)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `clap::Parser`
  --> src\main.rs:30:9
   |
30 |     use clap::Parser;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `Parser` in the root

error: cannot determine resolution for the derive macro `Parser`
  --> src\main.rs:36:14
   |
36 |     #[derive(Parser, Debug)]
   |              ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports

error: cannot find attribute `command` in this scope
  --> src\main.rs:37:7
   |
37 |     #[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
   |       ^^^^^^^

error: cannot find attribute `arg` in this scope
  --> src\main.rs:39:11
   |
39 |         #[arg(short, long)]
   |           ^^^

error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `parse` found for struct `main::Args` in the current scope
  --> src\main.rs:71:26
   |
38 |     struct Args {
   |     ----------- function or associated item `parse` not found for this struct
...
71 |         let args = Args::parse();
   |                          ^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `main::Args`
```

Very impressed with the clarity of Rust feedback. But I haven't managed to understand what's actually wrong here. As per the linked script my `dependencies` section of Cargo.toml includes this line:

`clap = "2.33.0"`

... anyone know what's wrong this time?

***Later***

After changing to `clap = "4.3.11"`. Still errors:

```
error: cannot find derive macro `Parser` in this scope
  --> src\main.rs:36:14
   |
36 |     #[derive(Parser, Debug)]
   |              ^^^^^^
   |
note: `Parser` is imported here, but it is only a trait, without a derive macro
  --> src\main.rs:30:9
   |
30 |     use clap::Parser;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

... + 3 more errors no doubt due to the above

Unfortunately I haven't got to that part of Rust 101 where you learn about "derive macros"...! I have no idea what that means.

Comment: 2.33 is quite an old version of clap (https://crates.io/crates/clap/versions). What happens if you install the latest version?

Comment: Thanks. See update. But the thing is, one might expect that script to run even with that old version. As you can see, the updated version also causes a fail, seemingly the same fail, "derive macro"...

Comment: To use derive macros, you'll need to enable the 'derive' feature of the library. Its not shown on the crates.io page, but is in the documentation: https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/_features/index.html. Try running `cargo add clap --features derive`

Comment: Thanks. Success! Is "features" and/or "derive" a thing across lots of crates? No doubt I'll find out in due course.

Comment: Features are a common concept. There's nothing inherently special about the word 'derive' (its just the name of the feature), but quite a lot of crates that use macros (the things in the square brackets) will call the feature needed to enable them 'derive'.

Comment: I think the original blog/script was mistaken, there is no `Parser` or `"derive"` feature flag in Clap 2.33. That functionality was only added in version 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(this answer added because question needs to be answered but not necessarily closed)

As stated by richzilla, the answer in this case is to use the [latest (stable) version of "clap"](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/) and to run this command first:

```
cargo add clap --features derive
```

"Features" being, as stated, a common concept in crates.